# JSON RouteLinks response to identify traffic light

Tags: here-api

I am sending an RME request to obtain speed limit and traffic light information and get back a JSON response. As Here-API provides a lot of different traffic sign types I dont care for (e.g. overtaking etc.) I cannot figure out how those types I am interested in are numerically encoded.

Browsing through the online docs provided by Here I could did not find the information I'm looking for, i.e. enumeration codes assigned to traffic lights

The request I send out looks something like

```
https://rme.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?
app_id=<my-app_id>
&app_code=<my-app-code>
&routemode=car
&file=<zip and base64 encoded route info>
&attributes=BASIC_HEIGHT_FCn(*),ROAD_GEOM_FCn(*),ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn(*)
&attributes=ADAS_ATTRIB_FCn(*),SPEED_LIMITS_FCn(*),TRAFFIC_SIGN_FCn(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below documents page and go to layers section and check the currently supported layers with the resource Layers.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/here-map-content.html

For examples, this link will show about the layer of TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC1 in detail.

https://fleet.api.here.com/1/doc/layer.html?region=WEU&layer=TRAFFIC_SIGN_FC1&app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}